# IIS is serving two versions of the same folder if virtual path is typed case insensitive

Tags: iis, case-sensitive, virtual-directory

If the user types the virtual path wrong such as test.com/user instead of test.com/User. IIS will return both /user and /User. I am lost on how to prevent this. The result i would like would be for it to return everything under /User regardless if typed /user.

*Note: In terms of this example I only have /User listed in IIS.

I have url rewrite installed in my iis, but i am having no luck

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule to achieve your requirement.

Details Url rewrite rule as below:

```
   </rule>
            <rule name="Prevent" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions >
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="user" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="AbortRequest" />
            </rule>
```